# Find in first value of nested object in Mongo Collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, find

I am trying to find docs by the first value of a nested object in a Mongo collection. Right now I am doing this:

```
Websites.findOne({
    $or: [
     {'obj.firstKey': {$regex: 'string'}},
     {'obj.anotherFirstKey': {$regex: 'string'}}
    ]
});
```

Is there an easier method, e.g.

```
Websites.findOne({
   'obj.[*]': {$regex: 'string'},
});
```

The first key name can be different in the obj. So targeting with a constant key name is not working in my case.

Comment: you want to perform based on dynamic key of the object ? if yes, what is the criteria of deciding that key ?

Comment: Yes the first key name is dynamic.